# Hint for showing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\prod_{j=0}^n{(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+2}})}}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need a hint for showing that the following series is convergent
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\prod_{j=0}^n{(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+2}})}}$$

What I have so far:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\prod_{j=0}^n{(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+2}})}}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\prod_{j=0}^n{(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}})}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}})^n}$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way for a more general problem: apply [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test) with 
$$a_n=\prod_{j=0}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{(j+2)^{\alpha}}\right).$$
and $0<\alpha<1$ (your case is $\alpha=1/2$). Then
$$n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}+1\right)=n\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{(n+3)^\alpha}}-1\right)=\frac{n}{(n+3)^\alpha-1}\to +\infty$$
and the series is convergent.

Comment: Oups... sorry for my incorrect comment that I’ll delete!

Comment: A nice use of Raabe's test (+1).

Answer (score 2):

**Only a hint as you requested...**

Naming

$$P_n = \prod_{j=0}^n{\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{j+2}}\right)},$$

take the logaritm $\ln P_n$ and use power series of $\ln(1-x)=-x -\frac{x^2}{2} -\dots$ around $0$.

You can then use comparison [integral test comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) to evaluate each term of the expansion convergence and take the exponential.